# CUFFT_INVALID_VALUE in cufftGetSize1d

Tags: cuda, fft, cufft

What is the proper way to use `cufftGetSize1d` (or any of the `cufftGetSize*`) functions?

I tried with:

```
cufftHandle plan;
size_t workSize;
cufftResult result;
cufftCreate(&plan);
result = cufftGetSize1d(plan, 1000, CUFFT_C2C, 1, &workSize);
```

However, the result of last call is always `CUFFT_INVALID_VALUE`, regardless of size, type, or batch i use. The same is with 2d and 3d variants. `cufftEstimate1d` works correctly.

Comment: I've been able to reproduce the error and at the moment cannot explain it.  I have observed that it fails this way on CUDA 6.5 and CUDA 6.0, but it seems to work correctly on CUDA 5.5   If I discover any additional information, I will report back.  Separately, `cufftGetSize` seems to work correctly.

Comment: I see the same thing with cufftGetSize3d() - worked in CUDA 5.5, fails in CUDA 6.5.  cufftGetSize() does what I need, so I will use it instead.

Comment: I submitted a bug report to NVidia. Their response is that they have reproduced it, and the developer team is investigating.

Comment: @RobertCrovella: Seeing as this seemed to have been a genuine bug which is now fixed in CUDA 7, would you care to upvote (and edit if you have anything to add) the community wiki answer to get this question off the unanswered queue?

Comment: @talonmies thanks for the pointer.  I've gone through the "unanswered" list as far back as beginning of 2015 and upvoted a few other languishing answers.  While doing so I came across [this Q with a CW answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33880248/the-difference-between-running-time-and-time-of-obtaining-results-in-cuda) and thought you might want to have a look.

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be a bug which was introduced during the CUDA 6 release cycle and subsequently fixed in CUDA 7. The following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cufft.h>

int main()
{

    cufftHandle plan;
    size_t workSize;
    cufftResult result;
    cufftCreate(&plan);
    result = cufftGetSize1d(plan, 1000, CUFFT_C2C, 1, &workSize);

    std::cout << "result = " << result << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

fails with CUFFT_INVALID_VALUE when compiled and run with the CUFFT shipped in CUDA 6.5, but succeeds when built and run against the CUFFT version in  CUDA 7.0. As noted in comments, `cufftGetSize` appears to work correctly in CUDA 6.5. So the workaround is to use `cufftGetSize` or upgrade to a newer than CUDA 6.5 version of CUFFT.

[This community wiki entry was added mostly from comments to get this question off the unanswered question list]