# the Difference between running time and time of obtaining results in CUDA

Tags: cuda, gpu, nvidia

I am trying to implement My algorithm on GPU using CUDA. this program work well but there is a problem. when I try to print out the results, they will be shown too late . 
here are some of my code. Assume True Results is not matter.

```
__device__ unsigned char dev_state[128];

__device__ unsigned char GMul(unsigned char a, unsigned char b) { // Galois Field (256) Multiplication of two Bytes
    unsigned char p = 0;
    int counter;
    unsigned char hi_bit_set;
    for (counter = 0; counter < 8; counter++) {
        if ((b & 1) != 0) {
            p ^= a;
        }
        hi_bit_set = a & 0x80;
        a <<= 1;
        if (hi_bit_set != 0) {
            a ^= 0x1b; /* x^8 + x^4 + x^3 + x + 1 */
        }
        b >>= 1;
    }
    return p;
}


__global__ void AESROUND()
{
    __shared__ unsigned char dev_rkey;
    __shared__ unsigned char dev_sh_state;
    int state_idx = blockIdx.x;
    int offset = ((state_idx / 4)) *4;

    for (int i = 0; i < 512; i++)
    {
        dev_rkey = dev_state[state_idx];

        dev_sh_state= GMul(dev_state[state_idx], 0x02) ^ GMul(dev_state[(state_idx + 5) % 16], 0x03) ^ dev_state[(offset + 5) % 16] ^ dev_state[(offset + 5) % 16];


        dev_state[state_idx] = dev_sh_state ^ dev_rkey;
    }


}
```

---

calling AESROUND

```
int main()
{

    unsigned char p[] = { 0x19, 0x3d, 0xe3, 0xbe, 0xa0, 0xf4, 0xe2, 0x2b, 0x9a, 0xc6, 0x8d, 0x2a, 0xe9, 0xf8, 0x48, 0x08 };

unsigned char h_state[128];
for (long long i = 0; i < 128; i++)
    h_state[i] = p[i%16];

cudaMemcpyToSymbolAsync(dev_state, h_state, 128, 0, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

clock_t start, finish;

start = clock();
for (long long i = 0; i < 1024; i++)

     AESROUND << <128, 128 >> >();
finish = clock();

float Time = finish - start;

printf("\n\nprocessing time: %2.15f (ms)\n", Time);

cudaMemcpyFromSymbolAsync(h_state, dev_state, 128, 0, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
printf("\n\state After Encryption:\n ");
for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
    printf("%x ", h_state[i]);

getchar();
return 0;
}
```

here are the Results:

```
processing time: 1.0000000000000 (ms)
```

-after a long time ( ~ 5 seconds), next line will be shown-

```
state after encryption:
88 91 23 09 78 65 11 87 65 43 56 71 20 93 18 70
```

as you can see, The processing time are too fast but the 128Byte will be shown Too late. 
why this happened? is this related to GPU? 
how can I fix it?

Comment: There is nothing to fix. Your timing is of the kernel is incorrect and you are only measuring the kernel's launch time, not execution time.

Comment: To extend what @talonmies said: Kernels are by default launched asynchronously. You can force a synchronization by calling `cudaDeviceSynchronize()` after the kernel launch (before `finish = clock()`) to get the "true" execution time. Additionally, you may want to read a bit about the async memory copy behaviors:  http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/4_1/rel/toolkit/docs/online/sync_async.html (I didn't find an online version of this for newer CUDA versions, but the essential information is covered there)

Comment: @Marco13: The up-to-date online version of the CUDA runtime API can be found [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/index.html)

Comment: @njuffa Thanks, I basically knew that, but did no see the corresponding section about sync/async in the newer docs - but obviously, here it is: https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/api-sync-behavior.html#api-sync-behavior

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The confusion here seems to have arisen out of using a host-based timing method to time what is (mostly) device activity.

Kernel launches are *asynchronous*.  The host code launches the kernel, and then proceeds without waiting for the kernel to complete.  Therefore this kind of timing:

```
start = clock();
for (long long i = 0; i < 1024; i++)

     AESROUND << <128, 128 >> >();
finish = clock();
```

is only measuring the kernel launch time.  (This is true even in this case where the kernel is launched repeatedly in a loop.  If some device queues are not exceeded, each kernel launch will be asynchronous, allowing the host thread, i.e. the for-loop, to continue.)

In order to measure the complete device execution time, you could do something like this:

```
start = clock();
for (long long i = 0; i < 1024; i++)

     AESROUND << <128, 128 >> >();
cudaDeviceSynchronize();   //wait for device to finish
finish = clock();
```